# Tags for pre-Sputnik topics

Tags: discussion, tags

A small but significant number of past and future questions involve space technology prior to the October 1957 launch of Sputnik 1.  There does not seem to be any dedicated tag for such topics.  **What are your thoughts regarding the tags for these topics?**

Two approaches involve putting everything preceding Sputnik into one tag:

1. Repurpose the existing [history](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag explicitly for this purpose.  Move anything post-Sputnik to a more appropriate tag.  There are over 360 questions with this tag.  It seems that people use this tag for anything they think is "old".
2. Create a new tag, such as [pre-sputnik](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-sputnik) or [pre-space-age](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-space-age), specifically for this purpose.

   > [pre-sputnik](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-sputnik)
   >
   > Questions about space personnel, agencies, and technologies prior
   >   to the October 1957 launch of Sputnik 1.

The other approach is to have specific tags for early topics, which *might* include the following.

3. Invention of the gunpowder rocket in China.
4. Konstantin Tsiolkovsky's work
5. Robert Goddard's work
6. Hermann Oberth's work
7. V-2 and other German WWII work
8. Operation Paperclip, Redstone Arsenal
9. NACA (NASA's predecessor).  I'd specifically like to see this one.

   > [naca](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naca)
   >
   > The National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics was the U.S.
   >   agency responsible for space flight from 1915 until it was absorbed
   >   by the creation of NASA in 1958.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I think you can probably just remove the part about repurposing a tag that's used hundreds of times for something you suggest it no longer be used for. That doesn't seem to be a reasonable thing to even raise.

Comment: Also, can you add something to your question that explains *why this tag would be helpful?* A "Should we X?" question needs to mention the pros and cons *before* listing the alternative ways to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the history tag should have any fixed limits. That said, I think as a guideline the tag should probably be used for only Shuttle Era (ended 2011) and before, at the present. As we move forward, naturally more items will become history, which is why I suggest no fixed limits.

I'm fine with having a [pre-sputnik](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-sputnik) tag in addition to the history tag. All you have to do is add it next time you have a question about that era. Some specific tags would be helpful too, like the NACA one you suggested.